# Pandas - column not found in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

I'm reading a csv file, frmo which I obtain these columns:

```
encoding = "UTF-8-SIG"
csv_file = "my/path/to/file.csv"
fields_cols_mapping = {
    'brand_id': 'Brand',
    'custom_dashboard': 'Custom Dashboard LO',
    'custom_dashboard_isfeatured': 'Custom Dashboard LO - Is Featured',
    'description': 'LODescription',
    'is_active': 'TrainingIsActive',
    'lo_id': 'LOID',
    'lo_type_id': 'LOType',
    'timestamp': 'Timestamp',
    'title': 'LOTitle',
    'training_version_id': 'TrainingVersion'
}

dataframe = pd.read_csv(
        csv_file,
        encoding=encoding,
        sep='|',
        usecols=[unicode(v) for v in fields_cols_mapping.values()],
        dtype={ k: object for k in fields_cols_mapping.keys() },
    )
```

However, while inspecting with ipdb I found that the parser called with `read_csv` doesn't convert the column name `Custom Dashboard LO – Is Featured`:

```
# debug
> /../../venvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py(1140)__init__()
1138             col_indices = []
1139             for u in self.usecols:
-> 1140                 if isinstance(u, string_types):
1141                     col_indices.append(self.names.index(u))
1142                 else:

ipdb> self
<pandas.io.parsers.CParserWrapper object at 0x10b134710>
ipdb> self.names
[u'LOType', u'LOID', u'LOTitle', u'TrainingVersion',    u'LODescription', u'TrainingIsActive', u'Custom Dashboard LO', u'Brand',     u'Custom Dashboard LO \u2013 Is Featured', u'Timestamp']
```

Does anybody have any suggestions about what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I changed the dict value but:

```
In [130]: dataframe = pd.read_csv(
   ...:             lo_csv_path,
   ...:             encoding=encoding_l,
   ...:             sep='|',
   ...:             usecols=[unicode(v) for v in fields_cols_mapping.values()],
   ...:             dtype={ k: object for k in fields_cols_mapping.keys() },
   ...:             )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call      last)
<ipython-input-130-670241506984> in <module>()
      3             encoding=encoding_l,
      4             sep='|',
----> 5             usecols=[unicode(v) for v in fields_cols_mapping.values()],
      6             dtype={ k: object for k in fields_cols_mapping.keys() },
      7         )

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the dash in the dataframe isn't the same as the dash in the dictionary.  The one in the dataframe is an en dash (`–` or `\u2013`), while the one in your dictionary is a hyphen (`‐` or `\u2010`).  They look similar, but they're not the same character, so the strings don't match.